# nonzero elements of sparse Matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

let's say I have a big Matrix X with a lot of zeros, so of course I make it sparse in order to save on memory and CPU. After that I do some stuff and at some point I want to have the nonzero elements. My code looks something like this:

```
 ind = M ~= 0; % Whereby M is the sparse Matrix
```

This looks however rather silly to me since the structure of the sparse Matrix should allow the direct extraction of the information.

To clarify: I do not look for a solution that works, but rather would like to avoid doing the same thing twice. A sparse Matrix should perdefinition already know it's nonzero values, so there should be no need to search for it.

yours magu_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct way to retrieve nonzero elements from a sparse matrix, is to call [`nonzeros()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html).

The *direct way* is obviously the **fastest** method, however I performed some tests against logical indexing on the sparse and its `full()` counterparty, and the indexing on the former is faster (results depend on the sparsity pattern and dimension of the matrix).

The sum of times over 100 iterations is:

```
nonzeros:   0.02657 seconds
sparse idx: 0.52946 seconds
full idx:   2.27051 seconds
```

The testing suite:

```
N = 100;
t = zeros(N,3);
for ii = 1:N
    s = sprand(10000,1000,0.01);
    r = full(s);

    % Direct call nonzeros
    tic
    nonzeros(s);
    t(ii,1) = toc;

    % Indexing sparse
    tic
    full(s(s ~= 0));
    t(ii,2) = toc;

    % Indexing full
    tic
    r(r~=0);
    t(ii,3) = toc;
end

sum(t)
```

Comment: The codes or comments for full and sparse seem to be switched.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin They are not. `r` is full already and I need to convert `s(...)` to full to get the end results, and that step falls into the timing.

Comment: Yes this was actually just what I was looking for (I mean nonzeros) The thing is. It seemed stupid to me to do the same operation (indexing twice). Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after but maybe `[r c] = find(M)` suits you better?

You can get to the values of `M` by going `M(r,c)` but the best method will surely be dictated by what you intend to do with the data next.

Answer (score 1):

[find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function is recommended by MATLAB:

> [row,col] = find(X, ...) returns the row and column indices of the nonzero entries in the matrix X. **This syntax is especially useful when working with sparse matrices.**

Comment: Find retrieves the subs vectors, which are already stored by the sparse object. `nonzeros()` retrieves directly the value without any additional indexing.

Answer (score 1):

While [find](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/find.html) has been proposed before, I think this is an important addition:

```
[r,c,v] = find(M);
```

Gives you not only the indices r,c, but also the non-zero values v. Using the *nonzeros* command seems to be a bit faster, but *find* is in general very useful when dealing with sparse matrices because the [r,c,v] vectors describe the complete matrix (except matrix dimension).